# If a directory doesn't exist, replace it with another one

Tags: .htaccess

I have a redirection problem that I don't know how to handle yet.

I have a directory, with different subdirectories leading to languages, ie :

```
http://example.com/en/
http://example.com/fr/
http://example.com/it/
```

etc..

What I'd like to do is, if the url contains a language that does not link to a directory created (for example, http://example.com/jp/ and I don't have a jp directory), it redirects it to the "en" directory.

I have the following rules for the moment :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/en/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Problem is, if I type `http://example.com/jp/something/blabla.jpg`, it redirects me to

```
http://example.com/en/jp/
```

What should I change in my rules ?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /en/$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I think it was the / at the beginning. Sorry, I can't test it out myself right now

Comment: Without the / at tbe beginning, works perfectly ! Thanks a lot Serg.